# Android studio arctic fox doesn't show modules in android window when import project from remote

Tags: android, android-studio-arctic-fox

In the android studio, arctic fox version 2020.3.1 pach3, developer A Creates a module, like "myapplication" in the following image, and there are three directories including "com.example.myapplication" in the android window then pushes it into the remote repository

[image]

, but when developer B pulls the project the "com.example.myapplication" directory vanishes as the following image:

[image]

However this issue didn't show up in the previous android studio versions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there wasn't any class in the myapplication directory and as soon as I created a class in it the directory showed up